# Should the Japan tag be used in this Death Note question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In many of my questions the Japan tag was removed. Should it be removed here? Or kept?

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70362

[Is it common to tell people how you spell your name in Japan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66508/is-it-common-to-tell-people-how-you-spell-your-name-in-japan)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is in context to names in Japan in relation to the series. The tag here is relevant to Japanese culture in general.

Comment: Are there / Can there be questions where culture tag is relevant but Japan tag is irrelevant?

Comment: Unless you are asking about specific custom of japan, the relevance of culture is implied.  As long as it pertains to culture in relation to anime/manga you can ask about culture depicted in other countries besides Japan. I.e. for culture/customs of Brazil from a series that has a setting in that country. The Japan tag can be tagged about events related to anime and manga in Japan. Such as pilgirmages to locations in Japan featured in prominently in anime or mnga